# Camel aggregation from two queues in Java DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I have two queues which having same type of objects in them.  I want to aggregate them into  a single queue through java DSL.  Could anyone tell me if this is possible?  If so, any code references?

Comment: *"Could anyone tell me if this is possible?"* is not a programming question.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I don't see why it's not.  He/she is asking if this is doable within the constraints of the Apache Camel framework.  I think this is completely legitimate, and a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is possible to do such a thing.
If you need just to drive them into a single route (without any aggregations, enrichments, etc.) you can just proceed with this piece of code:

```
from('direct:queue1')
    .to('direct:start');

from('direct:queue2')
    .to('direct:start');

from('direct:start')
//there goes your processing
```

If you need to aggregate them later on, use [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html). Or you can use example from java-addict301's answer if it solves your case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be doable in Camel using the [Content Enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) pattern.

Specifically, the following paradigm can be used to retrieve a message from one queue (where **direct:start** is) and enrich it with a message from the second queue (where **direct:resource** is).  The combined message can then be built in your **AggregationStrategy** implementation class.

```
AggregationStrategy aggregationStrategy = ...

from("direct:start")
.enrich("direct:resource", aggregationStrategy)
.to("direct:result");

from("direct:resource")
```